# Python, PIP, atom runner version and path issues

Tags: python, macos, pip, atom-editor

I'm having huge issues with Python versions...

if I run `"which python"`, I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python`

However, if I now run "python", python 2.7.1 launches.

If I type in `"which pip?`, I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip
```

If I now type in `"sudo pip install numpy"`. It installs to 3.4 just fine.

If I now type in `"sudo pip2.7 install numpy"`. I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Now if I go type `"python"`, version 2.7.1 launches. I type in "`import numpy"`, I get `"ImportError: No module named numpy"`.

My atom runner I'm assuming is pointing to system 'python'. I can't run runner python:2.7 though, it just ignores it.

Any help would be great... I'm running Mac, and I'm a newbie with python.

Comment: refer to your Python 3 as **`python3`**, half of the problems solved.

Comment: the problem is that **sudo** has a *different* path.